# tomcat log is strange

Tags: tomcat, log4j

my spring application use log4j ,it is run in tomcat 8.5.31, the configuration is default.

the `logger.info(foo)` in com.foo.foo1.A.java is print in localhost.log,it is not print in catalina.out.

But `logger.info(foo)` in com.foo.foo2.B.java is print in catalina.out

log4j.properties :

```
# This is the configuring for logging displayed in the Application Server
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, dailyFile,Hibernate

#stdout configure
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern= %-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [ %t:%r ] - [ %p ]  %m%n
log4j.appender.dailyFile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dailyFile.File = /xx/xx.log
log4j.appender.dailyFile.Append = true
log4j.appender.dailyFile.Threshold = DEBUG
log4j.appender.dailyFile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dailyFile.layout.ConversionPattern = %-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss-SSS} [%t] [%c]-[%p] %m%n

log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR

# Changing the log level to DEBUG will display SQL Hibernate generated
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=ERROR,Hibernate
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.QueryParameters=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan=ERROR

log4j.appender.Hibernate=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Hibernate.File=/xx/xxx.log
log4j.appender.Hibernate.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Hibernate.layout.ConversionPattern= %-d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss-SSS} [%t] [%c]-[%p] %m%n
log4j.appender.Hibernate.Append=true
log4j.appender.Hibernate.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.Hibernate.MaxBackupIndex=5
```

A.java ,B.java

```
  private final org.slf4j.Logger logger  = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

then where is the problem?

Comment: Please add the definitions of your `dailyFile` and `Hibernate` appenders.

Comment: @ Piotr P. Karwasz  it's already added

Answer (score 1):

i have found the problem, the context.xml has been modified by some people where is in the tomcat conf folder.

```
<Context swallowOutput="true">
```

after delete the `swallowOutput="true"` the log is now printed normally in catalina.out

tomcat official Website description is ：

```
Old applications that still use System.out or System.err can be tricked by setting swallowOutput attribute on a Context. If the attribute is set to true, the calls to System.out/err during request processing will be intercepted, and their output will be fed to the logging subsystem using the javax.servlet.ServletContext.log(...) calls.
Note, that the swallowOutput feature is actually a trick, and it has its limitations. It works only with direct calls to System.out/err, and only during request processing cycle. It may not work in other threads that might be created by the application. It cannot be used to intercept logging frameworks that themselves write to the system streams, as those start early and may obtain a direct reference to the streams before the redirection takes place.
```

It works only with direct calls to System.out/err, seem to work for log4j ?

Comment: At a very early stage ([`Catalina#initStreams`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Catalina.html#initStreams--)) Tomcat replaces the `System.out` object with its own wrapper. Everything that is initialized after, like your `org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender` will use the real stdout (`catalina.out`) or [JULI](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html) according to the value of `swallowOutput`. If you want to use Log4j all the way to the file, you need to install [log4j-appserver](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html)